# Insert a table between Nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

So i have this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<school name="AMU" location="CA">
   <student name="Jonny">
      <info age="20" class="A" />
   </student>
</school>
```

what i am trying to do is create only the table between `school` and `student`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<school name="AMU" location="CA">
   <table>
    .....
   <table />
   <student name="Jonny">
      <info age="20" class="A" />
   </student>
</school>
```

i know how to create a table im using for `each-group` and `concat` it.

XSL im working on,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="school">
      <xsl:element name="school">
         <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:attribute name="location">
            <xsl:value-of select="@location" />
         </xsl:attribute>
         <table>
            created table
         </table>
            <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="student" />
            </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem is that i want to copy all nodes below my table so my output XML will have the table between the `school` and the `student` and nothing else changed. (table works fine)

what should i do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your code is unnecessarily verbose. This:

```
<xsl:element name="school">
         <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:attribute name="location">
            <xsl:value-of select="@location" />
         </xsl:attribute>
```

could be replaced by this:

```
<school name="{@name}" location="{@location}">
```

or if you prefer, by

```
<xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
```

Then as to your question, you can replace this:

```
   <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="student" />
   </xsl:copy>
```

by this:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="student"/>
```